# SumatraPDF.exe as default PDF viewer

Tags: init-file, auctex, pdf

I'm using emacs (GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-17), and trying to define SumatraPDF as my default PDF-viewer for LaTeX. After some trials, nothing happens, and I have no idea why...

I wrote this in my .emacs-file (just after calling the [emacs-leuven configuration](https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven) ):

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'latex
  '(progn
     (if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
         (progn
           (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
                        '("Sumatra PDF"
                          ("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\" -reuse-instance"
                           (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search %b %n") " %o")))
           (assq-delete-all 'output-pdf TeX-view-program-selection)
           (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Sumatra PDF"))))))
```

And this is what I see in the buffer for the customization of the `TeX-view-program-list` :

```lisp
'(("Sumatra PDF"
   ("\"c:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\" -reuse-instance"
    (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search %b %n")
    " %o"))
  ("SumatraPDF"
   (concat "\"" "c:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe" "\" %o")))
```

Does someone have any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: You could try installing Sumatra in a path that doesn't include spaces (e.g., `C:\SumatraPDF`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to debug the issue you describe: It would help if you could assemble a minimal scenario how to reproduce this.

Meanwhile, I can suggest the following:

- Update your AUCTeX to lastest version (11.90.2) from ELPA.  It has builtin support for `SumatraPDF` on Windows.
- Put the directory `c:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/` into your `PATH` on Windows.
- Restart Emacs and check if Emacs finds `SumatraPDF` by evaluating this line:
  `(executable-find "SumatraPDF")`
- Add this single line in your init file, restart Emacs and open your .tex file:
  `(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "SumatraPDF")))`

Not related to your problem, I think `emacs-leuven` has a bug [here](https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/emacs-leuven.el#L6880):

```lisp
(when (or leuven--win32-p leuven--cygwin-p)
  (when (boundp 'TeX-view-program-list)
    (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
                 `("SumatraPDF"
                   (concat "\"" ,leuven--sumatrapdf-command "\" %o")))))
```

Observe where the `,` is.  This way, it adds a `concat` to `TeX-view-program-list` which will not work (see your question).  The correct way would be:

```lisp
(when (or leuven--win32-p leuven--cygwin-p)
  (when (boundp 'TeX-view-program-list)
    (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
         `("SumatraPDF"
           ,(list (concat "\"" leuven--sumatrapdf-command "\" %o"))))))
```

And for your code, I suggest you don't rely on `assq-delete-all` deleting items from a list.  To be on the safe side, do:

```lisp
(setq TeX-view-program-selection
      (assq-delete-all 'output-pdf TeX-view-program-selection))
```

Comment: I already had the latest version, but it worked just fine after adding the directory in the path ! thank you very much